# Lubuntu upgrade to Ubuntu17.10

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, 17.10, lxde

After upgrading I have bar on left side of display that looks like it could be launcher bar (Looks like venetian blinds) . It says it is LXPanel 0.9.3. I have minimized but pops up when I mouse over.
What is it and can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a second LXPanel.  To delete it merely right click on any open space on the panel and choose delete this panel.  However, if it is your only panel then you have some how moved it to the left side of your monitor.  In that case merely move it back to the bottom of your monitor by once again right clicking any open space on the panel and choose Panel Settings and change the position under Geometry.